# how to store client's data in the server

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, socket.io, webserver

When a client logs in, that client's data is stored in the server for further use, but when a new client logs in, the old client's data will be replaced with the new client.

So, if I store a client's data in **var** or **let**, it belongs to only one specific client.

Im doing this to reduce the loading time for new API calls and to delete the user from active users list when the webpage is reloaded (because socket.io connects again with new socketID)

Regarding my code, this is my first API call when the website starts

```
var list;
var find = (req, res) =>
  new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    user.find({}, { _id: 1, name: 1, email: 1 }).exec(async (err, user) => {
      if (err) return res.json(err);
      let p = await getfulluser(req.User._id); 
      list = user.filter((u) => u._id != req.User._id);
      for (let i = 0; i < p.messages.length; i++) {
        for (var e = 0; e < list.length; e++) {
          if (list[e]._id.equals(p.messages[i]._id)) {
            list.splice(e, 1);
            break;
          }
        }
      }
      res.json(list);
      resolve(list);
    });
  });
```

Here those '**for**' loops are time consuming things, so for the next API calls im using this method for better performance

```
exports.refreshfind = async (req, res) => {
  if (list) {
    let { id } = req.body;
    for (let e = 0; e < list.length; e++) {
      if (list[e]._id.equals(id)) {
        list.splice(e, 1);
        res.json(list);
        break;
      }
    }
  } else {
    await find(req, res);
  }
};
```

this method is lot faster than the previous one, but to do this i have to store the '**list**' in the server.

> Here the problem is when a new user(Let it be **user1**) logs in,first API will be called, '**find**' function will be executed, it's going to make '**list**' of '**user1**'.*Everything is fine here*

> Now an old user,who has already loggedin(Let it be **user2**) calls an API in a different web page.Server should execute '**refreshfind**' using the '**list**' of '**user2**'.But since before '**user2**' calling an API, '**user1**' has loggedin, executed '**find**' and made a '**list**' for '**user1**', *now that '**list**' of '**user1**' is being updated by '**refreshfind**' of an API which was called by '**user2**'*

In the same way to delete the user from '**active users list**'(Array) when the web page reloads.When a web page reloads socket.io executes disconnect and reconnects with a new socket.id

```
 socket.on("disconnect", ()...
```

so, the function to delete the user who reloads his page is

```
var userdata = require("./controllers/user");
 socket.on("disconnect", () => {
    if (userdata !== undefined && users !== undefined) {
      for (e = 0; users.length; e++) {
        if (users[e].userid === userdata.userdata._id) {
          users.splice(e, 1);
          break;
        }
      }
    }
    console.log(users);
    console.log("disconnected");
  });
```

Here the '**userdata**' is only one user's data stored for this purpose, and '**users**' is an array of active users.This '**userdata**' is called and imported frequently by a middleware, whenever an API is called by that user.

> So, when I do something in '**user1**' webpage, an API will be called and new '**userdata**' of '**user1**' will be formed.*Everything is fine till now.*

> Now when I reload the webpage of '**user2**', *'**user1**' will be deleted from '**users**' array instead of deleting '**user2**'*. This happens because before '**user2**' reloaded his page, '**user1**' had called an API and updated '**userdata**'(now this data belongs to **user1** only)

same thing happens to add a new logged in user to an array of '**users**'

```
var userdata = require("./controllers/user");
  socket.on("done", () => {
    console.log("connected");
    console.log(`u data ${JSON.stringify(userdata)}`);
    users.push({ userid: userdata.userdata._id, socketid: socket.id });
    console.log(users);
  });
```

> When i do something in '**user1**', an API will be called and '**userdata**' will be updated.*Everything  is fine till here.*

> Now if I login as '**user2**' in a different webpage, '**user1**' will be added into '**users**' array instead of adding '**user2**'. Because before '**user2**' logged in, '**user1**' had called an API and updated '**userdata**'(now this data only belongs to **user1**, not for every user)

Comment: Welcome! Could you elaborate a bit more as to what you are trying to do? Also providing a short code example of what you are doing currently might also help get a faster response.

Comment: please read my question again, i have updated it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Server works only for one client in a queue of clients. When you store a variable(var or let) for a client, and when a new client comes, those variables are going to change for the new client.So, you should not store anything regarding a client in variable

You can use **Redis** to store each client's data from the server, it's faster than HTTP request, so you will get better performance.